# Php to display carousel indicators depending on number of slides

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a bootstrap carousel that currently uses wordpress advanced custom fields to populate it. At the minute the carousel indicators are manually written. Instead I would the number of carousel indicators to be populated by the amount of slides there is. So if there is 2 slides there are 2 li's in the  carousel indicators ol.

Here is my php:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <?php $i = 0; ?>
        <?php while(has_sub_field('carousel')): ?>
            <div class="item <?php if($i === 0) { ?> active <?php } ?>">
                <img src="<?php the_sub_field('carousel_image'); ?>" alt="...">
                <div id="carouselLogo"><img src="<?php the_sub_field('carousel_logo'); ?>" alt="..."></div>
            </div>
        <?php ++$i; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on `while(has_sub_field('carousel')):` part of code, I suppose you have array in which you have stored slides data - in example code bellow I've named it *$slides*.

```
<?php
// Get slides and save them to array
// for example $slides = array();

// Open carousel wrapper
$output .= '<ol class="carousel-indicators">';

// Define slide No variable
// Bootstrap list begins with slide No 0, so we start slide numbering with 0    
static   $SlNo = 0;

// Foreach slide, output list item
foreach ($slides as $slide) {

    if ($SlNo == 0 ) {
        // Add class 'active' to first list item
        $output .= '<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="' . $SlNo . '" class="active"></li>';
    } else {
        // Output for rest of list items
        $output .= '<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="' . $SlNo . '" class=""></li>';
    };
    // Add +1 to slide No
    $SlNo++;
};

// Close carousel wrapper
$output .= '</ol>\n';

// Return and echo output
return $output;
echo $output;

?>
```

With this code we create output list item with *data-slide-to* number, for each slide item in *$slides* array.